# Customer custom attribute not saving while creating customer programmatically in magento 2.1.11

Tags: customer-attribute, magento2.1.11

I am using following code to create customer in magento 2 programmatically

```
namespace PackageName\ModuleName\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

// here $total_obj is customer array i am getting from third party service
foreach($total_obj as $arr){
    $customer = $customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->setEmail('customeremail@mail.com');
    $customer->setFirstname('FirstName');
    $customer->setLastname('LastName');
    $customer->setPassword('123456789');
    $customer->setLoginEmail('test@gmail.com');
    $customer->save();
}
```

from the above code i am not able to set login_email value. all details getting saved but not this custom attribute is not saving.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

for creation custom attribute i had followed https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-customer-custom-attribute-in-magento-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

**Customer custom attribute not saving while creating customer programmatically in magento 2.1.11*

**Reindex and flush cache then it should be work**

Run these command

```
 php bin/magento cache:flush
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setCustomAttribute to save custom attributes

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerRepository =$objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface'); 
  $customerId = 'you customer Id';
  $customerNew = $customerRepository->getById($customerId);              
  $customerNew->setCustomAttribute("custom_attribute_code","value");
  $customerRepository->save($customerNew);
```

This may help you. Please check this